# Calculate sum of time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, time

I have records in mongodb, time are string.

```
**Time**   
       
00:10:40
00:40:10
01:10:20
00:43:40
00:42:40
00:30:40
00:54:10
00:47:40
00:50:40
01:05:40
00:45:40
00:51:40
00:36:40
```

how to calculate sum of whole times?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your time strings in an array?

You can use something like this:

```
var hours = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var sum = '';

var myArray = ["01:40:40","03:50:50"];

var myFunction = function(){
  for(var i in myArray){
   hours += parseInt(myArray[i].substring(0, 2))
   minutes += parseInt(myArray[i].substring(3, 5))
   seconds += parseInt(myArray[i].substring(6))
  }
  if(seconds > 59){
    minutes += parseInt(seconds / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds % 60);
  }
  
  if(minutes > 59){
    hours += parseInt(minutes / 60);
    minutes = parseInt(minutes % 60);
  }
  sum = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  
  console.log(sum);
}

myFunction();
```

Feel free to ask if you have any other questions.

Comment: i found some error in above function  [ 00:02:00 , 0:2:0] it give 0:NaN:NaN

Answer (score 0):

```
**This may also work  :** 


    var time1 = "01:00:00";
    var time2 = "00:30:00";
    var time3 = "00:30:00";
    var hour=0;
    var minute=0;
    var second=0;
    var splitTime1= time1.split(':');
    var splitTime2= time2.split(':');
    var splitTime3= time3.split(':');
    
    hour = parseInt(splitTime1[0])+parseInt(splitTime2[0])+parseInt(splitTime3[0]);
    minute = parseInt(splitTime1[1])+parseInt(splitTime2[1])+parseInt(splitTime3[1]);
    hour = hour + minute/60;
    minute = minute%60;
    second = parseInt(splitTime1[2])+parseInt(splitTime2[2])+parseInt(splitTime3[2]);
    minute = minute + second/60;
    second = second%60;
    
    alert('sum of above time= '+hour+':'+minute+':'+second);
```